# Two answers from the same user on the same question

Tags: discussion, answers

I don't know what happened [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748910/how-do-i-make-a-button-stretching-to-the-entire-length-of-the-right-side-of-a-tab), but it seems that the question has [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748910/how-do-i-make-a-button-stretching-to-the-entire-length-of-the-right-side-of-a-tab/7749128#7749128) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748910/how-do-i-make-a-button-stretching-to-the-entire-length-of-the-right-side-of-a-tab/7748980#7748980) from the same user. Is that supposed to be possible? Why?

Comment: Multiple answers is what should be done if you have more than one solution.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Yes, but that edit button is also there for a reason, especially in cases like this, where the linked answerer is merely expanding on the same answer, and not constructing a new one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can post as many answers to a question as you want. The system warns you each time to make sure that you didn't mean to edit an existing answer instead, but you can click through this warning.

Comment: But WHY??? I mean why it is allowed?

Comment: Sometimes, you have two radically different but correct solutions. It makes sense to post them separately so that they can be independently judged by the community.

Comment: Okay! Clear now, I nearly suspect the man was hacking the SO! Haha! Since, I haven't try that.

Comment: I also sometimes post a 2nd answer if I find a better answer and my first answer has comments on it.

Answer (score 1):

Just had two moments in this April 2020 where found two users with more than one answer to one particular question. Once i've done that in [Game Development Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/176811/120353) (two answers with two different takes) and one of the moderators merged both answers and deleted one of them, so I assumed this was the right procedure overall.

Therefore, my take once saw the multiple answers from the same user was to flag them with moderator attention with a message similar to...

This user has more than one answer to this question which could be merged.

This morning was doing Late Answers Reviews and while flagging one noticed a message saying some of my latest flags weren't accepted. They were the two cases where the users had.

[In of of the times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51293775/5675325), the moderator says

> As long as they are using different approaches, it should be fine.

[In the other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3753916/5675325), the moderator says

> a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

[image: Multiple users from the same questions got the flags declined]

So, to answer your question, this might be something moderators deal differently depending on the community. While in Game Development Stack Exchange that isn't accepted and the moderator acted upon it directly, in Stack Exchange it's clearly accepted.

Comment: Despite all experimentation performed we've been unable to get moderators to operate as a single hive mind. The current mostly compatible situation is the best we can hope for short of continuous visits to the re-education camp